# MVC 4 Client Side Validation Showing Wrong Message

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

I have an MVC 4 application using client-side validation.  The form I am struggling with has multiple required fields, but I'm getting the same validation message for each field.

The Razor code looks like this:

```
<section class="input-label-group">
    @Html.Html5TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, InputTypes.InputType.Email, htmlAttributes: new { autofocus = "autofocus", autocomplete = "off"})                
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
</section>
<section class="input-label-group">
    @Html.Html5TextBoxFor(m => m.FullName, InputTypes.InputType.Text, htmlAttributes: new { autocomplete = "off" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FullName)
</section>
```

The model looks like this:

```
[Display(Name = "Email")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email address")]
[StringLength(128, ErrorMessage = "The email address may not exceed 128 characters")]
public string Email { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Full Name")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the user's full name")]
[StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "The user's name may not exceed 255 characters")]
public string FullName { get; set; }
```

But looking at the response from the server on initial page load (i.e. before any javascript has run), I get the following:

```
<section class="input-label-group">
    <input autocomplete="off" autofocus="autofocus" data-val="true" data-val-length="The email address may not exceed 128 characters" data-val-length-max="128" data-val-required="Please enter a valid email address" id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Email" type="email" value="" />                
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Email" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</section>
<section class="input-label-group">
    <input autocomplete="off" data-val="true" data-val-length="The email address may not exceed 128 characters" data-val-length-max="128" data-val-required="Please enter a valid email address" id="FullName" name="FullName" placeholder="Full Name" type="text" value="" />
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="FullName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</section>
```

Notice the data attributes for the second control refer to email not full name.  This causes the validation messages in the final form (using jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js) when submitting empty fields to look like this:

[image: Incorrect Validation Message]

I must be missing something obvious, any thoughts?